# How to scrape number of fans of a public Facebook Page using importXML

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-sheets, google-drive-api

Trying to figure out how to use Google Spreadsheet's ImportXML function to scrape the number of fans of a public Facebook Page.﻿

This does not work:

```
=ImportXML("https://www.facebook.com/RBReich/likes", "//span[@class='timelineLikesBigNumber fsm']")
```

This formula also doesn't work:

```
=ImportXML("http://graph.facebook.com/RBReich?fields=likes","//pre")
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Could not fetch url: http://graph.facebook.com/RBReich?fields=likes
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this script made public by Martin Hassman, found here http://labs.met.cz/ (scroll down a bit), and find this: [Facebook Likes Counter](https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0AqxQZA5PONnpdDhKSTdnZ2ZqVkJGem5lUVdIUnlud2c)
Just copy the Google Sheet and adapt the code to your needs.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very nice spreadsheet.

I also found this simple formula works as well: 

`=REGEXEXTRACT(importdata("http://graph.facebook.com/"&K2&"?fields=likes"), "\d+")`